# You can "allocate the slot S for X", but what's a verb V that will work in a sentence such as "Please V X into the slot S"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

In "*Please V X into the slot S*", the word order is such that

- V immediately precedes S, and
- the preposition *into* is then used.

That's what I need. Clearly you can *put* or *insert* X into slot S. But I am after a verb which conveys a similar sense to *allocate*, connoting that you have arranged or earmarked or allocated a special slot into which you then deposit the item X.

Comment: Assign, perhaps?

Comment: Perhaps the slot itself can do the work:  *Please insert X into/through dedicated slot S*

Comment: Is there really some reason you *need* “into” to be used here, as opposed to any other preposition?

Comment: At least ged rid of *into to*, which is not likey to fit many places.

Comment: "Into to" was a typo - now corrected. "Into" is best in the context of the surrounding sentences. Letting the slot do the work is a good idea - I'll think about that.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use "into". You say you don't want action, you just want theoretical allocation, but "into" implies movement.

Comment: ........... tidy?

Comment: the whole premise is faulty.  Allocating slot S is an operation on S.   But using a verb on X is an operation on X. They can never be equivalent.

Comment: Allocating S to X creates an association, but no explicit action. *Allocate* usually means that some kind of choice was possible, and that a decision has been made (even a programmatic decision). An S has been chosen for X. In contrast, the construction “V X into S” requires us to know something about what kind of operations can be performed on X. It’s possible that *allocate* itself could be used, but if it can’t, we need to know more about X before we can answer.

Comment: You designate the big slot for quarters. Then you assign quarters to the big slot.

Comment: @Jim yeah good point. Wow. Therefore instead of “Please V X into slot S” the question would be “Please V S with X” - where Ive kept the referrants the same but the part-of-speech labels (if one was thinking that way where X is direct object etc) are not applicable anymore. Example “Please target slot S with the envelope of money”.

Comment: @Consc good catch your comment is same as Jim’s. Hence my reply above is to you too

Answer (score 0):

Appropriate, as a verb, is the best I got. Then use “to” not “into”, maybe either.

Deposit helps us just a little; it indicates intent and care but not assignment. Dedicate is better and seems to fit the need but then sounds doesn’t sound right, again with “to”.

Dedicate or appropriate. Or even **direct**.

**Please direct the money into slot S.**

None are perfect; if we could put an adjective on the slot instead would be easy, “correct”, “appropriate”, “designated” (which is even better than “dedicated”) etc.

Comment: Tough crowd in this se.

Comment: The designated slot